# SignalR not invoking method on server

Tags: c#, angularjs, signalr

I'm using AngularJS to create a SignalR service that connects to the hub that I specify and exposes the `.on` and `.invoke` methods so my controllers can listen for events from the server and invoke methods on the server.

Here's the relevant part of my service:

```
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                hub.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $root.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            ready: function (callback) {
                return isLoaded.then(function () {
                    callback();
                });
            },
            invoke: function (methodName, args, callback) {
                return hub.invoke.apply(hub, $.merge([methodName], $.makeArray(args))).done(function (result) {
                    $root.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            connection: connection
        };
```

My hub is connecting perfectly, however when I try to call my invoke, nothing happens. Here's where I call it:

```
    var chatHub = hub('chatHub');

    chatHub.on('userConnected', function (user) {
        console.log(user);
    });

    chatHub.ready(function () {
        chatHub.invoke('Connect', [ // also tried 'connect' here
            { Name: $root.auth.profile.name, Picture: $root.auth.profile.picture },
            { RoomKey: $routeParams.roomKey, RoomID: $routeParams.roomId }
        ]);
    });
```

So if you look at the `.ready()` function that is returned from my service, it uses a promise that when it's resolved will execute my callback passed to it. That works great (the promise `isLoaded` is resolved in my connection.start().done() which is called inside my service when it's instantiated, so it'll only execute the callback after it's successfully connected)

It gets to my `.invoke` method (I've confirmed this with console.log), but never invokes the method on the hub, below:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub {
    public async void Connect(User user, Room room) {
        // ommitted
    }
}
```

The objects I pass to it have this structure:

```
public class Room {
    public int RoomKey { get; set; }
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
}
```

So I don't think it's an issue with my arguments, since nothing is required on them so it won't complain that I only passed a few of the arguments (the only ones I need).

For clarity's sake, in my `chatHub.invoke('Connect', ...)` I'm using the case it is on the server based upon this code I found in my `~/signalr/hubs` file (I don't need this since I don't use the generated proxy, I just included it for the meantime so I could inspect their underlying code)

```
    proxies['chatHub'] = this.createHubProxy('chatHub'); 
    proxies['chatHub'].client = { };
    proxies['chatHub'].server = {
        connect: function (user, room) {
            return proxies['chatHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['chatHub'], $.merge(["Connect"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Should you be calling chatHub.invoke('connect',...) instead?

Comment: Oh man. I think you're right. I had it named UserConnect at one point but I did a lot of ctrl z when I was debugging and fixing another issue. I'll test once I get back in front of a computer.

Comment: I do that all the time - also remember it converts to javascript naming conventions so when the hub method was UserConnect the invoke should use 'userConnect'.

Comment: I was under the impression when you used the `.invoke().apply()` method and passed it in the `$.merge()` you should use the case that it is on the server. I've always used the generated proxy and done the camel case like you mentioned though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I've always used the generated proxies as well so I'm not sure on that one, but thought it followed the same conventions...let me know what you find when you get back and test it.

Comment: I've switched them so they're both `Connect`, and I've tried `connect` on the client as well. Neither hit my breakpoint in the Hub, unfortunately. I've edited my question to reflect the new values.

Comment: Figured it out! See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, finally figured it out. There were two separate problems I was having.

**Problem Number One:**

```
chatHub.ready(function () {
    chatHub.invoke('Connect', [ // also tried 'connect' here
        { Name: $root.auth.profile.name, Picture: $root.auth.profile.picture },
        { RoomKey: $routeParams.roomKey, RoomID: $routeParams.roomId }
    ]);
});
```

This code was passing an array of data to `.invoke()`, and then that:

```
        return hub.invoke.apply(hub, $.merge([methodName], $.makeArray(args)))
```

was making an array of that array. So simply change that to:

```
        return hub.invoke.apply(hub, $.merge([methodName], args))
```

and it's fixed.

Then I figured, I should probably add some error logging to this to see if it's actually erroring and I'm just not doing anything with it (no `.fail()` and therefore never seeing it) So I changed it around to:

```
        return hub.invoke.apply(hub, $.merge([methodName], args))
            .done(function (result) {
                $root.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(result);
                    }
                });
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                $log.error('Error invoking ' + methodName + ' on server: ' + error);
            });
```

Which gave me this **amazing** error message and **Problem Number Two**:

```
Error invoking connect on server: Error: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
```

Which makes sense because my method on the server was an `async void`, I switched it around `async Task` and voila, it worked. It's now hitting my breakpoint successfully.